# Fill holes on cave generated by cellular automata

Tags: python, algorithm, flood-fill, cellular-automata

I'm generating caves for a game. The caves are 50x50 matrix builded by cellular automata, where 0(purple) is wall and 1(yellow) is empty space (where the player can move).[Here is an example of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCIpc.jpg)

I pointed out my problem with the red circles. There are "holes" in the walls which are unreachable by the player. I'm trying to fill this holes but I cannot. Basically I want to turn 1 surrounded by 0 into 0.

I have tried to use floodfill with this approach to do this:

First I count how many cells I paint with floodfill from a starting point x,y. If this count is less than 16 and greater than 1 then I actually paint the cells.

```
for x in range(0, WIDTH - 1):
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT - 1):
        number_cells_paint = floodfill_count(cellmap, x, y, number_cells_paint)
        if 16 > len(number_cells_paint) > 1:
            floodfill(cellmap, x, y)

        number_cells_paint = []
```

*number_cells_paint* is an array where I append every cell I visit in *floodfill_count*. This is how I think to count inside recursive algorithm and probably where my mistake is.

This is floodfill_count:

```
def floodfill_count(cellmap, x, y, number_cells_paint):
  cellmap_aux = cellmap
  if len(number_cells_paint) > 16:
      return number_cells_paint

  if cellmap_aux[x, y] == 1:
      cellmap_aux[x, y] = 0
      number_cells_paint.append(cellmap[x, y])

      if x > 0 and cellmap[x - 1, y] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x - 1, y, number_cells_paint)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x + 1, y, number_cells_paint)

      if y > 0 and cellmap[x, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x, y - 1, number_cells_paint)

      if y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x, y + 1, number_cells_paint)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x + 1, y + 1, number_cells_paint)

      if x > 0 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x - 1, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x - 1, y + 1, number_cells_paint)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x + 1, y - 1, number_cells_paint)

      if x > 0 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x - 1, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill_count(cellmap_aux, x - 1, y - 1, number_cells_paint)


  return number_cells_paint
```

and floodfill:

```
def floodfill(cellmap, x, y):

  if cellmap[x, y] == 1:
      cellmap[x, y] = 0

      if x > 0 and cellmap[x - 1, y] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x - 1, y)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x + 1, y)

      if y > 0 and cellmap[x, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x, y - 1)

      if y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x, y + 1)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x + 1, y + 1)

      if x > 0 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x - 1, y + 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x - 1, y + 1)

      if x < WIDTH - 1 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x + 1, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x + 1, y - 1)

      if x > 0 and y < HEIGHT - 1 and cellmap[x - 1, y - 1] == 1:
          floodfill(cellmap, x - 1, y - 1)


  return cellmap
```

This implementation of floodfill works, I have tried before so my problem is on floodfill_count.

With this code I have [this final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBk4I.jpg)

Comment: less than 16 and greater than 1 are numbers chosen by me. If I don't limit the number of cells painted it'll paint all the map and I don't want this.

Comment: Why aren't we filling the *"hole"* at coordinates (25,25) please?

Comment: I just pointed out some of the holes as example of this particular output, not all of them, but yes I would like to fill that hole too.

Comment: What is floodfill_mine? (It is not defined in given code samples)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It was the older function name. It's fixed now thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do a single flood fill starting from the edge of the screen (or the player's starting point, wherever that is) and the remove any empty space that was _not_ touched by the flood fill?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I was also thinking that :-) but what if the seed for the floodfill sadly got chosen inside a cave?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, that was the first thing I tried and sometimes it get stuck inside a cave. Thank you for the replay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `cellmap_aux = cellmap` this line of code. Python assigned lists as a reference, so any changes to `cellmap_aux` would be the changes in `cellmap` (therefore `floodfill_count` paints all the field). `cellmap_aux = cellmap.copy()` should be used instead.